# How you call pickup truck's trunk cover?

Tags: truck, pick-up

I'm not sure i'm in right place or wrong.

I'm planing buy Tacoma pickup. So i'm researching about it's parts. But problem is English is not my natural language. I don't know how you call that cover part of trunk. If you still don't get what I asked watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DhJ3wL8vozA :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The truck in that video has a *cap* or *camper shell*. The cargo area of a pickup truck is usually called the *bed*; *trunk* is the rear luggage area on a passenger car.